# Arrangement of letters in the word $MINCEMEAT$ with condition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the number of different ways in which all $9$ letters of the word $MINCEMEAT$ can be arranged if NO vowel $(A, E, I)$ is next to another vowel.
Can anybody help me in this question?

Comment: I changed the title of your question because it was a terrible title. Next time try to add something like this. :)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Your permutations will look something like this - * A * E * I * E *, where at least one consonant must be in the middle three *s. First, permute A,E,I. That's $4\times 3\times 2/2=12$ ways. Now, you have 5 consonants left, two of which are M. Let's say for now the two M's are distinct.

Then you choose three of the five consonants  to fill the middle three *'s. That's ${5\choose 3}=10$ ways. But then you can permute them in 6 ways, so that's 60 ways.

Now 2 consonants left and your word is looking like - * A * _ * E * _ * I * _ * E * where the three _'s in between have been filled and the *'s are available places. There are 8 *'s, so $8 \times 8$ places for the two.

Then those two consonants need to be permuted as well, so 2 ways for that. So far, the total is $12\times 60 \times 64 \times 2$.

But we assumed the two M's were distinct. So divide by 2. We end up with $12 \times 60 \times 64 = 46080$ ways.

EDIT: As people in the comments indicated, there is some double counting here. I'll call the number I got above an upper-bound.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, because you are counting arrangements such as MINCEMETA more than once since you count it once when you place the C, then place the N to its left and again when you place the N, then place the C to its right.

Comment: nice comeback with the EDIT! :D

Comment: Yeah, surprisingly hard question. Looking forward to an answer now.

Comment: @RohitPandey same here, having this up on a page and refreshing it from time to time. Also trying to solve it of course

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was an over-estimation and @user247327 is an under-estimate. I want to give this another shot and hopefully, this attempt will stand up to peer review. This one does lie between @user247327 and my old answer, but closer to @user247327. As before, we know that the words will look like -

```
                                         * A * E * I * E *
```

And as before, there are 12 permutations for the vowels. Now, we fill up the consonants into the positions given by the five stars. The question is how many consonants each star gets. We know that the middle three stars can't get less than one consonant.

Here are the possibilities:

```
                                           1 1 1 1 1 _(1)
                                           2 1 1 1 0 _(2)
                                           0 1 1 1 2 _(3)
                                           1 2 1 1 0 _(4) X3
                                           0 2 1 1 1 _(5) X3
                                           0 2 2 1 0 _(6) X3
                                           0 3 1 1 0 _(7) X3
```

We repeat configuration (4) three times because the 2 can be at any of the middle three stars. So, the total configurations for the consonants are 15.

In each configuration, we can permute the consonants in $\frac{5!}{2!}$ ways (because 2 M's).

This would make the total configurations: $12\times 15 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 = 10800$.

Thanks to @N.F. Taussig for reviewing and pointing out corrections. Also, the 15 configurations I enumerated above are basically $6 \choose 4$ and one can see this if the consonants are placed first. See comment by @N.F. Taussig below.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  - can you please peer review this one and see if there is still some double counting?

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa - does this one look right?

Comment: This is better.  However, you forgot about $0 3 1 1 0$.  There are three such cases, giving you a factor of $15$ rather than $12$.  With that correction, you will obtain the correct answer of $10800$.

Comment: It is easier to first arrange the five consonants.   Doing so creates six spaces where we can place a vowel, four between successive consonants and two at the ends of the row. $$\square C_1 \square C_2 \square C_3 \square C_4 \square C_5 \square$$  To ensure that the vowels are separated, choose four of these six spaces for the vowels, then arrange the vowels in those spaces.  The consonants can be arranged in $\frac{5!}{2!}$ distinguishable ways.  The spaces can be selected in $\binom{6}{4}$ ways.  The vowels can be arranged in the selected spaces in $\frac{4!}{2!}$ ways.  Now multiply.

Comment: Nice, easier indeed. So the 15 ways I hashed out manually above basically get replaced by $6 \choose 4$. This deserves to be its own answer, but referenced your comment in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer has been deleted, I presume that because it was not quite correct.  But it was very close to being correct and was a very clever attempt and I will follow that!  There are 9 letters, 5 consonants, and 4 vowels.  In order that no two vowels be together the "form", taking "C" to represent a consonant and "V" to represent a vowel, the vowels and four of the consonants must be of the form CVCVCVCV or VCVCVCVC.  We can then put the fifth C at any of the 5 places beside a V.  That is, there are 2*5= 10 such combinations.  The 4 vowels are I, E, E, A, four vowels, two of them the same.  There are $\frac{4!}{2!}= 12$ ways to order them.  The 5 consonants are M, N, M, C, T, five consonants but, again, two the same.  There are $\frac{5!}{2!}= 60$ ways to order them.  That gives a total of 10(12)(60)= 7200 ways to do this.

Comment: What about VCVCVCCCV. I think cases like this are not being covered by your assumption? Might be wrong.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect for the reason Rohit Pandey indicated.